# PGFPlots: Externalizing Images and pdflatex -shell-escape <filename>

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot, tikz-external

I want to externalize images using the commands:

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
```

The PGFPlots Manual says to use `pdflatex -shell-escape <filename>`. I'm assuming I should type this into the command line, but nothing is happening when I do. I need to do something similar to use GNUPlots, which is also not working for me.

My test file's name is `abcd`.

**Update:** I also tried changing `\tikzexternalize` to `\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18]` and wrote `pdflatex enable-write18 abcd.tex` into the command line. The result was identical.

I'm using Windows 8 and I am not very computer savvy.

At the end, you'll find a series of images of what I am doing.

Hopefully, once this is figured out, I will be able to use GNUPlots as well...

---

MWE from PGFPlots Manual, which does not work at all...even minimally...:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot {x^2};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Our first external graphics example}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot {x^3};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{A second graphics}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

1. Compiling without typing anything into the command line, I get the error from the first picture (pasted into notepad to increase font size).
2. Next, I go to the command line and type this and get a dialogue box...and nothing more happens with the command line. In fact, I can't type anything more into it.
3. Last, I compile the my file `abcd` again in TeXworks and get the same error from Step 1.

[image]
[image]

Comment: regarding 2.: did you install the missing package?
regarding 3.: in Texworks you somehow must configure the command which is run when compiling. Here you also need to put in the -shell-escape

Comment: I clicked "Install", which I assume installs the missing package. About #3, what do you mean by "here you also need to put in the `-shell-escape`"? Where is "here"? Where in TeXworks do I put it? In the preamble? In Settings>Typsetting>Something? Can you please be more specific. All the manuals I've read say, "Then you put in `-shell-escape` there and it should work, but nobody seems to say what "there" refers to.

Comment: do you have administrator rights? If not, that could be the problem why the package is not being installed.

"Here" does mean in Texworks. I don't use Texworks, but somewhere in the options, there should be a possibility to specify how the compilation is being done. There, you should insert the option. I for example use Texstudio and there you can go to Options > Configure Texstudio > Commands where you find the command for compiling. For me it is "pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex" but for Texworks, the syntax could be different (especially with the %-sign)

Comment: I double-checked the tex files and I do already have the required file, which is dehypth exptl, which is a package concerning the special hyphenation of German words. I'm not sure why the package is necessary or why I would need to install it when I already have it. .........I will get back to you about configuring TeXworks compiling. I'm going to try it right now.

Comment: Also, I do have system administration privileges.

Comment: @bene: http://i.imgur.com/RIUdNMs.png. I typed that line into TeXworks. I saw on one website it needs to be pdflatex -shell-escape. Also, TeXworks says in the error messages I need to type pdflatex -shell-escape. I also tried many variations, including -shell-escape <filename>, enable-write18, shell-escape...countless variations. Do I THEN need to use the command line again? I tried that as well and it doesn't work either...this is beyond frustrating.

Comment: this texworks looks strange for me. try for Program "pdflatex.exe" and for the arguments only "-shell-escape". Texworks should convert this then to "pdflatex -shell-escape FILENAME" and send this to the command line.

Comment: It is always advisable to install a FULL MiKTeX distribution.

Comment: @bene Once Harish solved my gnuplot issues, the externalization issues went away. Problem solved. (I had selected a checkbox during the gnuplot installation that would add gnuplot to the system path.)

Comment: On that basis, off-topic.